# Retain query string parameters after authorization fails in MVC

Tags: url, redirect, model-view-controller, authorization

I have a task in which I have to make sure to do a particular action (open a popup) on the basis of some url parameters in the query string when a user clicks a link from an email, but suppose the user is not logged then the authorization fails as the action I am redirecting the user to is has the authorize attribute, 
I show a page here saying authorization has failed  and then there is a link through which the user can log in and get redirected to her landing page.
Unfortunately the URL parameters get lost.
I have them in the filtercontext when function HandleUnauthorizedRequest gets hit, how do I flow this URL after login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flow the information of the original intent or destination in the login screen when the user is not logged in.

One standard way to do this would be to include the information in the query string e.g. `http://blah.com/login?continue=<url encoded original url>`. When the user successfully logs in, simply see if the query string had a value and then redirect the user there, if not just do the default action of login.